# A question about decompositions of rational functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, fields, functional-equations, complex-dynamics, rational-functions

Let $f_1,g_1,f_2,g_2$ be non-constant rational functions on the Riemann sphere (i.e. elements of $\Bbb{C}(z)-\Bbb{C}$) satisfying $f_1\circ g_1=f_2\circ g_2$. Suppose there is a prime number $p$ such that at least one of  $f_1$ and $g_1$ belongs to $\Bbb{C}(z^p)$. Can the same be said about $f_2$ and $g_2$?

Update: The example from the comments is a very special one in which $g_1=f_2$ is linear, hence a conjugacy between dynamical systems $f_1=z^2$ and $g_2=z^2+2z$. I am interested in examples where the maps are all non-linear. There is a very special family of maps in complex dynamics that includes power maps, Chebyshev polynomials and [Lattès maps](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0402147.pdf). I am in particular interested to see if there is any example where $f_1$ or $g_1$ is in $\Bbb{C}(z^p)$, but on the other side $f_2$ and $g_2$ are not conjugate to any map from the family mentioned above.

Comment: No. For example $p=2$, $f_1=x+1$, $g_1=x^2$, $f_2=x^2+x$, $g_2=x+1$.

Comment: @LeechLattice: I think you mean $f_1=x^2$, $g_1=f_2=x+1$, $g_2=x^2+2x$.

Comment: Thank you both of you.

Answer (score 3):

This question is discussed in the paper by S. Lysenko
[On the functional equation f(p(z))=g(q(z)), where f and g are meromorphic functions, and p and q are polynomials](http://jmage.ilt.kharkov.ua/jmag/pdf/2/m02-0068r.pdf). (Russian. English, Russian, Ukrainian summary)
Mat. Fiz. Anal. Geom. 2 (1995), no. 1, 68–86.

Comment: Thank you professor Eremenko.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9606217